# Are positive, comparative and superlative adjectives considered as modes?

Tags: terminology

Are positive, comparative and superlative adjectives considered as [modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood)?

Can I call each of them as mode? For example: **positive mode**, **comparative mode**, and **superlative mode**?

Comment: Usually they are called [degrees](https://www.worldclasslearning.com/english/adjective-degrees-of-comparison.html).

Comment: I would say adjectives have three forms: the (plain) adjective, a comparative form and a superlative form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The word you want is *grade*, or alternatively *form*.

Examples:

*The comparative and superlative g͟r͟a͟d͟e͟s͟ of adjectives and adverbs.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=6fF_AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA38&dq=%22grades%20of%20adjectives%22&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=%22grades%20of%20adjectives%22&f=false)
...*many adjectives one or two syllables in length inflect for 
g͟r͟a͟d͟e͟* *(e.g. plain* old *vs comparative* older *vs superlative* oldest *).* ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 27)

On the other hand, [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346) uses *form*:

*[Adjectives] can take comparative and superlative f͟o͟r͟m͟s͟.* (p. 403)

Grammatical *mood* (or *mode*), which is what your Wikipedia link is about, has nothing to do with adjectives; it is entirely about verbs.

Comment: I basically agree with you but have a question: You say no, the word you want is grade. When I say things like that, I get into trouble. Do you? [I am upvoting by the way]. I think forms works too.

Comment: @Lambie Well, not so far... only a matter of time, though, I'm sure. I agree that  'forms' works too, as 'form' is a broad concept that applies to all kinds of inflection,e.g. of verbs, pronouns, adjectives, and adverbs.  'Grade', however, is specifically about adjectives and adverbs. (Thanks for upvoting!)

Comment: @Lambie I've added *form* as an option since that is what [ComGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Comprehensive-Grammar-English-Language-General/dp/0582517346) uses. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No worries and thanks. I am getting paranoid about making any comments at all....:)

Comment: In another book called "Cambridge Grammar of English" (p.439) by Ronald Carter and Mccarthy, it refers to positive form as the **base form**.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point Yeah, that makes sense.